# How to make the contents of JDialog to appear from starting (or) top of the JDialog instead of from the middle?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, jdialog

How to make the contents of `JDialog` to appear from starting (or) top of the dialog instead of from the middle?

Comment: Have a look [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Use the appropriate layout manager and constraints. Pack the dialog to make it the right size. General tips: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height.